Probability that a probability will be less than a certain value
Suppose I have a nonnegative random variable $X$ and I don't know its expected value, but I know that its expected value is less than or equal to $a$ with at least probability $p^*$. i.e, $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X)\leq a)\geq p^*$. In this scenario, what can I say about $X$? I want to be able to say something like $\mathbb{P}(X\leq \delta)\geq p$. Is there anyway I can derive $\delta$ or $p$ from the given information? The following is my attempt and it is so weird. What would be a standard way to make such a statement?
$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X)\leq a)\geq p^*$. For a fixed $\epsilon>0$,
$\iff \mathbb{P}\left(\cfrac{\mathbb{E}(X)}{\epsilon}\leq \cfrac{a}{\epsilon}\right)\geq p^*$
By Markov's inequality,
$\implies \mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq \epsilon\right)\leq \cfrac{a}{\epsilon}\right)\geq p^*$.

$\mathbb{E}[X]$ is deterministic; it is just a number. This doesn't mean that you can't ask what $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}[X] \le a)$ is; however, the value will always $0$ or $1$ because there is exactly zero dependence on $\Omega$. Thus, it would be a better question to ask how we can bound $\mathbb{P}(X \le \delta)$ if $\mathbb{E}[X] = a$.

@J.S. I think the question is about estimating the expectation (we do not know it) and then the probability is actually in general neither $0$ nor $1$.

@J.S. Thank you for your comment but like Peter said, I am interested in the case where the expected value is not known.

@Peter Yes, you are correct. I can only estimate the expected value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The expression "$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X)\leq a)$" doesn't make sense without a probability space in which "$\mathbb{E}(X)\leq a$" is an event. There is not automatically a probability associated with something just because you don't know it. However, ...

...If you have another random variable $\theta$, which we think of as a parameter that controls the (conditional) distribution of $X$, then "$\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(X|\theta)\leq a)$" is well-formed because the conditional expectation is a random variable. But if you don't know anything about $\theta$, then $\Bbb E(X|\theta)$ doesn't tell you much about the (marginal) distribution of $X$.

@Peter I would raise the same point as Karl; there is not a probability distribution associated to $\mathbb{E}[X]$ unless the choice of $X$ is itself random, which could be interpreted and formalised in a variety of ways. Returning to this, it is quite an interesting question, but it is not written as clearly as it could be.

@Karl If I know the distribution of the random variable $\theta$ which influences the expected value, how can I make use of it? Thank you for your help.

Hmm, I think my last statement was confused. If the distribution of $\Bbb E(X|\theta)$ is all you know, then learning the distribution of $\theta$ gives you no extra information about the distribution of $X$. We have e.g. $\Bbb E(X)=\Bbb E(\Bbb E(X|\theta))$, and I guess you're looking for other general statements like this relating the variables $X$ and $E(X|\theta)$. (If instead you know exactly how $\theta$ influences $X$, i.e. you know the joint distribution of $(\theta, X)$, then you also know the exact distribution of $X$.)

Suppose that we have a finite measure space $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mathbb{Q})$, where each element $X \in \mathbf{X}$ is a random variable $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ for some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Then, we can write:
$$\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{E}[X] \le a) \le \mathbb{Q} \left( \mathbb{P}(X \ge \varepsilon) 
 \le \frac{a}{\varepsilon} \right)$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$, by identical reasoning to that in your post.
The reason why your working looks unusual is because it uses $\mathbb{P}$ for both the measure on $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, which does not really make sense formally. Moreover, it is necessary to first be able to define a sensible measure space $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mathbb{Q})$; for instance, with parametric distributions, as Karl suggests.
You may also find it interesting to consider the product space $(\Omega \times \mathbf{X}, \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{X}, \mathbb{P} \otimes \mathbb{Q})$.
Edit: If we have a random variable $W : \Lambda \to \mathbb{R}$ defined on another probability space $(\Lambda, \mathcal{L}, \lambda)$, and a family of random variables $X_w : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ (for each $w \in W(\Lambda) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$), we could define $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mathbb{Q})$ with reference to $W$ as:
$$\mathbf{X} = \{X_w : w \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$\mathcal{X} = \{X_A : A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$$
where $X_A := \{X_w : w \in A\}$, and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and
$$\mathbb{Q}(X_A) = \mu_W(A)$$
where $\mu_W = \lambda \circ W^{-1}$ is the law of $W$.
Then, for instance:
$$\mathbb{Q}(X : \mathbb{E}[X] \le a) = \mu_W ( w : \mathbb{E}[X_w] \le a) = \lambda(\mathbb{E}[X_W] \le a)$$

For example, suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{U}[0, W]$, where $W \sim \mathcal{U}[0,1]$. Then, $\mathbb{E}[X_w] = \frac{w}{2}$, so for $a \ge 0$,
$$\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{E}[X] \le a) = \mu_W (\mathbb{E}[X_w] \le a) = \mu_W \left( \frac{w}{2} \le a \right) = \min(2a,1)$$.

Thank you for your answer. It clears up a lot of the confusion for me. If I know the distribution of the random variable $W$ which influences the expected value of $X$ and if I think of it as a conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|W]$, how would your answer change?

@curiosity I think there is more than one way to formalise what you describe. I admit I'm not sure exactly how Karl would formalise it as a conditional expectation, though not impossible to figure out. I'll edit to give another construction which I think works.

I would greatly appreciate it. I learn a lot from the discussion with you. Thank you so much for your help.

You're welcome!

I just saw your edit on the answer. Wow, it would take me a while to digest it. I may have follow up questions. Please bear with me and I appreciate your patience.

I suspect for clarity (and possibly other technical measure theory reasons) we should formalize situations like "$X \sim \mathcal{U}[0, W]$, where $W \sim \mathcal{U}[0, 1]$" in terms of conditional distributions instead of "RVs whose values are RVs in another space". Otherwise statements can get confusing/ambiguous - for example, is this $X$ uniformly distributed?

@Karl I used $X \sim \mathcal{U}[0,W]$ as short-hand for $X_w \sim \mathcal{U}[0,w]$ (I am sure you understood, but I agree that it is not written in the most unambiguous way.) I am not sure from where the measure-theoretic issues would arise, but I do agree that an interpretation in terms of conditional distributions is likely better for clarity. I thought it would be a little bit of a pain to write out, but do feel free to write another answer.

Yeah, sorry for being pedantic. Maybe there are no issues if we can avoid events/variables that combine randomness from both spaces, like "$X_W$". Such an object doesn't exist in your formulation, whereas in the conditional formulation it is just $X$.

@J.S. So, $(X,\mathcal{X},\mathbb{Q})$ is also a probability space right? I don't quite understand how you define $\mathcal{X}$; it seems like you are trying to construct a $\sigma$-algebra. I also don't understand $\mu W$. Could you please provide more details? Thank you so much.

@J.S. Perhaps it is common notation but I don't know what you mean when you index a random variable with a real number, I don't know what it means for example $X_w$.

@curiosity Hi, yes, $(\mathbf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mathbb{Q})$ is a probability space. The intuition for the definitions of $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mu_W$ is that they are used to transport the structure of $\Lambda$ onto $\mathbf{X}$ via $W$. For instance, $\mu_W$ is an example of a pushforward measure; it pushes forward the structure of the measure $\lambda$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ as described in the link.

@curiosity The indexing is simply to say that there exists a random variable $X_w : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ for every $w \in \mathbb{R}$,; equivalently, for each $w \in \mathbb{R}$, we have a random variable $X_w$. You could also interpret this as a function $\mathbb{R} \to {\text{ r.v. } \Omega \to \mathbb{R}}, ; w \mapsto X_w$. The purpose of this in the construction is so that we can identify this family of random variables $\mathbf{X} = (X_w)$ with a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then, the pushforward measure $\mu_W$ gives a measure on $\mathbf{X}$ via this identification.

@J.S. I am learning so much. I am not from the field. I appreciate you.

@curiosity No problem! I find measure theory to be a lot of fun, and the question you asked is intriguing.

@J.S. OMG, I got it! I finally got it. Thank you so much. I learned so much from you past few days.

@curiosity Glad to hear it!
